# KeyError: "None of [Index(...')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using the `recordlinkage` library with `pandas`. In the first step, I created indexes, the parameters are:

```
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.block(fr.iloc[:, 2])
pairs = indexer.index(fr)
```

Notice, that the page of project indicates the following usage:

```
 indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
 indexer.block('orignal_link')
 candidate_links = indexer.index(dfA, dfB)
```

I replaced the column label with the same position (`.iloc`). It couldn't find any column name. However, when I specifically asked for the column names, I got the following output:

```
Index(['_id', 'doi', 'orignal_link', 'title', 'authors', 'affiliation', 'citation', 'abstract', 'paper', 'references'], dtype='object')
```

Anyway, after replacement the produced error is following:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([('https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5097416', 'https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5110298', 'https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5096407', 'https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5093609', 'https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5094748', 'https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5098007', 'https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5095979', 'https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5109249', 'https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/12/7/073006/meta')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

If it's not finding values, how can it print them out?

Any help?

Thank you